# Struggling to add two 'one-to-many' relationships to the same child object in SwiftUI with Core Data

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I’m using SwiftUI and Core Data.  My Core Data stack is setup as a one-to-many relationship.

There are several different entities that are configured this way. However, my issue in question is in regards to two entities that are each in a one-to-many relationship with one entity. Specifically these are both Supplier and Account that are in relationship to Quotes.  So Supplier is a one-to-many to Quotes, and Account is a one-to-many to Quotes.

The project is setup so that the user first enters an account, where they can then add a quote to that account. While the user is adding their quote, they can also add a supplier.  I have it so that the user can successfully add a quote to their account, however the supplier object does not save.  I’m at a loss about why, but I believe it’s a simple solution.

I will put my code below with info about what each does. Please let me know if more code or clarity is needed.  I have tried to omit irrelevant info and code.  Towards the end of these code pieces, there is a reference to a “QuoteClass”. This is a system I’ve been using that temporarily holds attributes before they are saved to the persistence store. I can add this, but again it’s just the attributes that are getting stored. So things like quoteName, quoteDateAdded, quoteTotalCost etc.

This is the Core Data entity for Accounts (Parent object one), except for its attributes,:

```
extension AccountCoreData {
    static func accountFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<AccountCoreData> {
        return NSFetchRequest<AccountCoreData>(entityName: "AccountCoreData")
    }
    @NSManaged public var accountToQuote: Set<QuoteCoreData>?
}
```

This is the Core Data entity for Supplier  (Parent object two), except for its attributes:

```
extension SupplierCoreData {    
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SupplierCoreData> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SupplierCoreData>(entityName: "SupplierCoreData")
    }
    @NSManaged public var supplierToQuote: NSSet?      
}
```

This is the Core Data entity for quote  (child  object), except for its attributes:

```
extension QuoteCoreData {    
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<QuoteCoreData> {
        return NSFetchRequest<QuoteCoreData>(entityName: "QuoteCoreData")
    }   
    // quote to objects
    @NSManaged public var quoteToAccount: AccountCoreData
    @NSManaged public var quoteToSupplier: SupplierCoreData?
     
}
```

An extension to the NSManangedObjectContext, which I have not had much luck with.

```
    // for matching supplier to quote
    func supplierFromID(withID id: UUID?) -> SupplierCoreData? {        
        guard let id = id else { return nil }        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<SupplierCoreData>(entityName: "SupplierCoreData")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "supplierID == %@", id as CVarArg)
        request.fetchLimit = 1        
        do {
            return try self.fetch(request).first
        } catch {
            print("No supplier found; Error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }        
    }
```

This is the picker where the user selects the supplier they want to attach to the quote, as they are making that quote.
The binding for the SupplierID property is connected an @State property wrapper in a view above this one.

```
struct AddEditQuoteNumberSupplierView: View {    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: SupplierCoreData.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [])
    var supplierCoreData: FetchedResults<SupplierCoreData>        
    @Binding var supplierID: UUID?
var body: some View {        
        VStack {          
          // picker
          Picker("", selection: $supplierID) {                                
             ForEach(supplierCoreData, id: \.self) { supplier in                                    
                 Text(supplier.wrappedSupplierName)
                   .tag(supplier.supplierID)
                 }
             }
        }        
    }  
}
```

And here is where I’m trying to save that new object to its persistent storage.

```
extension AddQuoteSaveButton {  
    private func saveQuote() {        
        let newQuote = QuoteCoreData(context: moc)
        newQuote.savesQuoteClassToCoreData(quoteClass)        
        if moc.hasChanges {            
            if let supplier = moc.supplierFromID(withID: supplierID) {
                supplier.addSupplierToQuote(newQuote)
            }            
            accountCoreData.addQuoteToAccount(newQuote)            
            DataController.shared.saveContext()            
            notificationCenter.addCalendarNotification(
                id: quoteClass.quoteClassID,
                for: quoteClass.quoteDateFollowUp,
                calendarTitle: quoteClass.quoteName,
                calendarSubTitle: quoteClass.quoteFollowUpNote)       
        }        
        dismiss()        
        print("Account: \(accountCoreData.wrappedAccountName)")
        print("Quote: \(newQuote.wrappedQuoteName)")
        print("Supplier: \(newQuote.quoteToSupplier?.supplierName ?? "-?-")")        
        // resets
        quoteClass.resetQuoteFields()        
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the code that is meant to display the supplier name, should it be stored properly to Core Data

```
struct MainQuoteView: View {    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc    
    @ObservedObject var quoteCoreData: QuoteCoreData
    var body: some View {
            Text(quoteCoreData.quoteToSupplier?.wrappedSupplierName ?? "-?-")
                .foregroundColor(.pink)                    
    }
}
```

So far, I’ve tried the following without much luck: I’ve tried to access the objects ID’s by way other UUID’s, and match those up to their respective objects. So I’ve tried to send the UUID of the supplier object to match it to its respective quote object.  I’ve also tried mirroring what works for matching the supplier to its account, by way of attaching its supplier to its quote. Neither of these have worked.